# Visual Studio Web Application in another localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, xampp, localhost

I have a web site with Xampp running at "localhost:83", and a C# ASP.NET page in Visual Studio 2013 Web Application running at "localhost:53619".

I'd like to make this C# page a part of my localhost:83 site. For an exemple, to have a link in my main site to access this C# page whenever I want.

I made a link to this page, but it only opens successfully when the project from Visual Studio is already running. I want it to open independently from the Visual Studio project. I don't know if I could just throw the files into my site's folder or I should do something more specific.

Comment: did you try to acces with IP Adress? i hope it will work

Comment: You normally need to [Publish your website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20yh9f1b%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) and specify to put it wherever your root for Xampp is. Note: This might not be available in your version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Well you can put IIS on your machine and host it there, or there's ways to host ASP.NET with Apache and mod_mono. But IIS is the more common solution by far.

Comment: @Equalsk All versions of VS 2013 can publish. And if you wanted to server the content with XAMP then you need mod_mono for the ASP.NET server side bits.

Comment: could you guys send a link for this mod_mono, just so I know how it works?

Comment: @LuisEduardo You have access to search engines, right?

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP does not natively support ASP.NET.

You have to host your application on an IIS Webserver (can be activated in Windows Control Panel) or IIS Express.

When you start the project in Visual Studio, Visual Studio starts IIS Express.

Normally IISExpress is located at **C:\Program Files\IIS Express**. There is the file iisexpress.exe you have to start.

To configure IIS Express you can modify the configuration file located at ***"C:\Users\Username\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config"***